# Electron setWindowOpenHandler do not work with a bootstrap datatable print function

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In a web app created with `Electron JS` I have to open some links in the system's default browser.

I do this with this function inside my `main.js`

```
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    require("electron").shell.openExternal(details.url);
    return { action: 'deny' }
  })
```

This function is perfect and any external url link that I call with target "_blank" is opened in the default OS browser.

Unfortunately I also use the bootstrap datatable library and **the print function of the datatable with this procedure is no longer works** and it is not possible to modify the print datatable to avoid opening the print popup.

I wanted to create an personalized function in main.js like this:

```
function OpenBrowser() {
  require("electron").shell.openExternal('www.google.com');
  return { action: 'deny' }
}
```

**Now i would like to call this function via javascript in the remote web page with `onclick="OpenBrowser()"`

Unfortunately I can't make the web page communicate with the function inserted in the `main.js` of electron

Has anyone already faced this problem and managed to solve it? Does anyone have any other solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.